# Keyboard delay - missing last character

Tags: keyboard

I recently installed elementary OS 0.3.2 64-bit and am experiencing a weird keyboard behavior when typing.

After a few seconds when everything is OK,  the following happens:

Characters are  not displayed immediately, I need to type the next character before the one before appears.

It is not a lag - it simple waits for next keyboard event. Restarting usually helps but only for a short time, then the problem will re-appear.
I made a few experiments end research and found:

- it is not a hardware problem (I tested more keyboards)
- it affects all users
- many programs are **not** affected, be example Chrome, xterm, Atom editor etc.
- it seems that most of affected programs are Elementary defaults by example scratch editor, terminal, etc. But also Guake terminal is affected.
- Live version booted from USB is **not** affected at all.
- Slow keys, bounce keys and similar functions of Universal access are **Off**.

Does anybody have some idea?

Comment: Could you give a summary of which modifications to the system you may have made and which extra applications you have installed?

Comment: Only added nvidia driver, openssh, atom editor, chrome, libreoffice 5 and guake terminal. I suspect nvidia driver because with nouveau it seems ok.

Comment: I also have this problem. It doesn't happen in Windows 10

Comment: Fixed by reinstalling

Comment: Maybe it is the NVIDIA driver

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Elementary, and every other distro that I installed, on my laptop.

It turned out to be an issue with the way my **Nvidia GTS 250m** video card behaved with newer Nvidia proprietary drivers. It caused the keyboard lag you mentioned, but was a slight improvement over the frequent crashes that I experienced with the Nouveau driver.

The solution was to downgrade to the `nvidia-graphics-drivers-304` proprietary drivers. It has it's own fantastic set of issues, but is stable and doesn't cause this bizarre text/visual issue, either.